# iCarousel currentItemIndex doesn't change

Tags: objective-c, indexing, icarousel

So I'm using iCarousel to display some images in my app and I need a label to show current image index when I scroll (e.g. "3/10"). This is my code:

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    NSLog(@"index: %i", currentItemIndex);

    imageNumber.text = @"";        
    imageNumber.text = [[[imageNumber.text
                      stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currentItemIndex+1]]
                     stringByAppendingString:@"/" ]
                    stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", carousel.numberOfItems]];    
}
```

Although this method is being called whenever I scroll, the currentItemIndex never change. It remains 0.
Does anybody know why is this or can suggest another way I can update the index when the user scrolls the carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to have

```
    carousel.currentItemIndex
```

and not `currentItemIndex`.

Second, you may also implement `carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:` delegate and check for the index:

```
- (void)carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    NSLog(@"index: %i", carousel.currentItemIndex);
}
```